# How to enable the.net core web api to receive request form any subdomain?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

I want to develop a reverse proxy in .net core api and I want to use subdomains to route requests to different services. Subdomains are not specified already rather it will be processed dynamically

I have tried to use the following CORS policy 
but my middlewares does not capture any request coming through subdomains rather only handle which are coming from http://www.localproxy.com

```
namespace OrchestratorReverseProxy
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddCors
            (
                options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                        builder => builder
                            .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                            .WithOrigins("http://*.localproxy.com")
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .Build()
                    );
                }
            );

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseMiddleware<DarkLaunchMiddleware>();
            app.UseMiddleware<ReverseProxyMiddleware>();

        }
    }
}
```

The browser shows response like

This site can’t be reached www.the.localproxy.com’s server IP address could not be found.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: Can you show us your `Configure(...)` method?

Comment: Please see the above code section, I have pasted my complete startup.cs